# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I've posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399089/storing-the-correct-answer-to-check-against?noredirect=1#comment68048350_40399089) and it's getting quite the negative reviews. Apparently I'm asking for code reviews, which I have to disagree with because I'm asking for best practices and good/better ideas. Is it "illegal" to ask for that? If anyone sees anything wrong with the question do tell so I can change my question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: The comments you're getting explain it quite well.

Comment: " 
There ain't no "best" for all use cases. Instead of using that tiresome phrase, add context for yours, and exemplify the different coding approaches." I feel like I've done this

Comment: Then the question would be *too broad* AND opinion based. If you want a poll...SO is not the place.

Comment: I have written down 3 ways that I've thought of already and I'm asking if anyone would select either or if they have a better way

Comment: Fair enough, should I add it to dba instead?

Comment: Check their guidelines first...requests for **opinions** are rarely a good start though.

Comment: Is it good enough to get the job done?  Probably.  Will it still work when the site gets popular and gets a thousand hits a second.  Probably not.  The only obvious "best practice" is to not get popular.

Comment: @HansPassant what are you referring to?

Comment: @g3mini at your proposed solutions mentioned in your original question.

Comment: @Glorfindel so they'd all work but none are a good idea because of performance?

Comment: @g3mini The point is that "best practice" is meaningless.

Comment: Then how is it called when for example you have a many-to-many relationship and it's [...] to create a pivot table?

Comment: @g3mini: doing your job :)

Comment: Good point. Do you have tips on how rephrase my question? @Gimby

Comment: @g3mini I don't really think you can to be honest, your question is asking for a discussion and opinions; very much the exact opposite of what SO is for. Your question reads like a dream, well done on that front. But its material for a discussion forum, not a Q&A site.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment regarding the markup =) & you're right, I'll try to remove it

Answer (score 2):

To wrap things up; the problem was that the question was more discussion based than it was answerable.